# How can I check percent GPU usage on Windows?

Tags: windows, gpu, system-monitoring

Windows includes the **Task Manager** tool that shows **CPU usage** in a graphic manner.

This is useful on multiple cases, i.e: to detect rogue sites that use your computer for bitcoins mining. But some of these sites or viruses use the **GPU power** instead, which is not shown in Task Manager.

What method could I use to **detect percent of actual GPU usage**?

Accepting both command-line and GUI solutions.

Comment: [Find out how hard your GPU is working with Windows Task Manager](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/windows-10-task-manager-gpu-usage/) Released as part of the Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 16226 to insiders on the Fast ring, the new GPU tracking task manager offers some detailed information about your graphics cards and how they are working. The Task Manager can now tell you which graphics card you are running and what driver version you have and when they were updated.

Comment: This is not strictly a question requesting software recommedations, but a way to solve a problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use an older Windows version that doesn't show the GPU usage in Taskmanager you can use [ProcessExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to [show the GPU usage](https://betanews.com/2011/07/20/process-explorer-15-adds-gpu-monitoring/):

[image]

in system information of in a column (`View` --> `Select Columns` --> `Process GPU` --> `GPU Usage`):

[image]

An opensource solution is [Process Hacker](https://github.com/processhacker2/processhacker) which also offers GPU usage in system information (via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

[image]

and as column (right click on header and click "Choose columns"):

[image]

[image]

Comment: A very good solution: not open source, but free, and a small program that requires no installation. Thanks you.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez I've added a link to an opensource solution.

Comment: Add to default graphs on Process Explorer: `View --> Select Columns --> Process GPU --> GPU Ussage`.

Answer (score 3):

> What method or tool could I use to detect actual GPU percent usage?

You can use Task Manager in Windows 10 Version 1709+

> [image]

[Find out how hard your GPU is working with Windows Task Manager](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/windows-10-task-manager-gpu-usage/)

Comment: @agcala - Please limit commentary to feedback about my answer.